# Object persisted as JSON

Tags: java, jpa, datanucleus

I have the following entity

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Lob @Convert(converter = JsonAttributeConverter.class)
private Object data;
}
```

I want this persisted as a string not binary array. If I put the annotation
`@Column(name="data", columnDefinition="mediumtext NOT NULL")` (I'm using MySQL), then when trying to persist I get the error *Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05t\x07...' for column 'data' at row 1*

The problem is that DataNucleus tries to persist this as a BLOB instead of CLOB.

Is there any workaround here? (except using a @PrePersist method and an additional field)

I'm using org.datanucleus:datanucleus-accessplatform-jpa-rdbms:3.3.2.

Comment: Why don't you like the idea of `pre-persist` with an additional field?

Comment: Tried using DataNucleus extension @JdbcType ? http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jpa/annotations.html#JdbcType

Comment: @AndreiI Because then the model will depend on the JSON library, which, in my opinion, is not a good design choice.

Comment: @DataNucleus No, but I will and let you know the outcome.

Comment: OK, but you have already made such a problem, in which you depend on data nucleus (the @Converter) annotation.

Comment: From where is JsonAttributeConverter? If you worte it, could you provide the code for it ?

Comment: Yeah, but this is in the annotations, not the class itself. Annotations can be ignored, members not :).

Comment: If that annotation will get ignored, you will get exceptions on runtime, which is IMHO worse that on deployment :)

Comment: @Andrei, presumably the JsonAttributeConverter is a JPA 2.1 AttributeConverter (like Convert annotation is), hence JPA standard.

Comment: @DataNucleus presumably so (although clearly it is not). If that converter class JsonAttributeConverter.class (not annotation) won't be found or won't have a reference to the JSON library, there will be a part of the application that will throw Exceptions, because an Object won't be able to be persisted in the String column. I mean the effect of using the entity listener is the same as using this annotation (but of course this is a architecture problem and not a dependency problem).

Comment: You can discard an annotation at compile time, supposing that you want to use the domain model in some other application.

Comment: Do you mean remove annotations from compiled code? If you really mean at compile time, could you give me some references to read more about it?